# sfx path not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, setup-project

I'm making a setup proyect in Visual studio for my application, and I have a small problem.

I want to copy a huge bunch of files to some folder (my documents -> TEST). So I made a silent self extracting .exe file with WinRAR. When you double click that file, it automatically creates the folder "FILES" in the same folder it's located and self extracts everything to that folder.

So, when you double click that files.exe file, located in "D:\Documents\TEST", it extracts all files to "D:\Documents\TEST\FILES".

In the setup project, I did this:
-I added to the file system the folder "User's Personal Data Folder" and inside that folder I created the folder "TEST", and I added files.exe there.
I created a custom action in the commit section, to run that files.exe file.

But when I install my application, it creates the folder "D:\Documents\TEST" correctly, it copies the .exe file there, but for some reason it creates the "FILES" folder in the location C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and extracts the files there, in "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FILES".

How can I prevent that?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Running something as a custom action from an MSI-based install isn't the same as running the same code from the interactive user's environment. The working directory when you run a custom action typically comes from the windows installer service that's running the code - there's no magic that automatically makes the working directory the same as where the executable started from. This means that any code must specify the exact path of any file locations and not rely on a working directory. So it looks like the code in the program just creates a "FILES" directory which is being created in the working directory of the process, which is the 32-bit windows system location.

I don't know if you wrote the code, and it's not clear why your comment refers to environment variables. However, any .NET programmer would use Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments. If you want to ask Windows Installer for the location you ask for the PersonalFolder property from this list:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties

and your question says you are installing to the "my documents" folder, which is User's Personal Data Folder from the list in the setup project (File System view). So you should be installing to that folder in the setup project. If you are more explicit about what the code does and exactly how you call it as a custom action then any answer can be more thorough.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  But as far as I know, there's no environment variable for "my documents" folder, so I don't know how to get the exact location of that folder for my sfx file. Any ideas?